# snmptrapd unknown snmp version 193

Tags: snmptrapd

I'm trying to capture SNMP traps using snmptrapd but don't seem to be receiving anything.

I installed snmptrapd and then modified the /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf file to have `authCommunity log public` and started the service with `systemctl start snmptrapd`.

Upon start my syslog has "unknown snmp version 193" printed to it but nothing else and when I send traps it doesn't seem to output anything or throw an error.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a reason for "unknown snmp version 193" but it seems you need to specify an output file as it won't do it by default.

My snmptrapd.conf now looks like:

```
authCommunity log public
[snmp] logOption f /var/log/snmp
```